# Python+HTML Sumar dos numeros si la contraseña es correcta

Tags: html, python, funciones, contraseña

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, es algo simple. Tengo en un archivo "form.html" que intenta sumar n1+n2 y te da el resultado unicamente si la contraseña ingresada es correcta. El html tiene 3 campos input:

- n1
- n2
- contraseña

Tengo un archivo "envio.py" con una función que intenta hacer lo que cité anteriormente. Me funciona la parte de la contraseña pero no suma los números, los concatena (ya probé haciendo el pasaje a entero con **int()**.

Detallo lo que escribí en cada archivo.

> envio.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def template():
    return render_template("form.html")

@app.route('/usuario',methods=['POST'])

def usuario():
    n1 = request.form['n1']
    n2= request.form['n2']
    nombreUser = request.form['nombreUser']
    if nombreUser=="hola":
        # EL PROBLEMA ESTÁ EN LA LÍNEA SIGUIENTE:
        return "<h1> La suma es: " + n1+n2 + "</h1>"
    else:
        return render_template("errorpass.html")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> form.html:

```
<form action="/usuario" method="post">
    <label for="n1"> Ingresa el n1 </label>
    <input type="number" name="n1"><br/>
    <label for="n2"> Ingresa el n2 </label>
    <input type="number" name="n2"><br/>
    <label for="nombreUser"> Ingresa el pass </label>
    <input type="text" name="nombreUser"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Comment: También podrías primero realizar la suma y almacenar el valor en una variable, y después agregárselo al string con f format algo así `f"<h1> La suma es:  {suma}</h1>"`

Answer (score 2):

Seguro el problema tiene que ver con que `n1` y `n2` son cadenas. ¿Has probado esto?

```
"<h1> La suma es: " + str(int(n1) + int(n2)) + "</h1>"
```

(Perdona mi español!)

Comment: si, perfecto, muchas gracias!

Comment: Otra solución usando *f-strings*:  `f"<h1> La suma es: {int(n1)+int(n2)}</h1>"`